# Optimize Search Result from address book in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

When ever user search then I want to search that query against address book data for anything like name , phone number , url, email addres. My solution is working fine but it is slow . If address book data is huge , app gets stuck. How can I optimize the search , so that my application won't hang even in large address book data?

Here is my code

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    [self takeSomeActionWhenTextChange];  
}

-(void)takeSomeActionWhenTextChange{
    [contactArray removeAllObjects];
    NSString *searchText=[[textSearchBar text] lowercaseString];


    for (int index=0; index<count; index++) {
        ABRecordRef record=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, index);
        //[self checkStringISAddress:searchText withRecord:record];
        if ([self checkStringIsFirstName:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        || [self checkStringIsLastName:searchText withRecord:record] == YES
        ||[self checkStringIsNote:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        || [self checkStringIsAddress:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        || [self checkStringIsCompany:searchText withRecord:record]==YES 
        ||[self checkStringIsEmail:searchText withRecord:record]
        ||[self checkStringIsPhonenumber:searchText withRecord:record]==YES )
        {
            NSLog(@"object added inside Array");
            [contactArray addObject:record];
            [contactTableView reloadData];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"No Match For this object");
            [contactTableView reloadData];

        }

    }

}
```

I will check if substring from search query matches with first name, last name , email & so on. Above methods contain logic to check if substring is present or not? If ti matches , i will add it to array else not.

SHOULD I USE THREAD OR GCD TO PERFOEM SEARCH ? IF YES , HOW? HOW CAN I UPDATE MY TABLE VIEW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GCD, you should still show an activity indicator to show the user that something is happening though. It will only prevent the main thread blocking, and the UI locking up.

Not tested, you can of course set the priority of the queue using different constants too:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //Perform the search
    //perform your search here...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Update the UI
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

You might also want to look at using predicates rather than just checking substrings, might give you some cleaner logic.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So do you mean instead of manually checking , I should use NSPredciate ? if yes can you tell me how can I use Predicate?

Comment: Searching SO for "NSPredicate" should give you lots of examples. Documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

Comment: Thanks for link. I saw this doc. But my problem is how can I use predicate to search my query against all the properties like first name, last name, address, notes, email, ph no etc? Should I use one predicate per property or is there any other way? Because I have to search against all the properies mentioned above.